# Is there a reliable software to convert dll into lib for c++ application?

Tags: libraries, dll, c++

The situation is described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532280/failed-to-link-mysql5-1-39-bin-libmysql-dll-in-a-c-project

Is there a **free** and **working** tool?

Comment: I fear if this get's migrated to SO it will get closed, since it's hardly a question to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

See if one of the following articles helps:

[Generate a .lib from a DLL with Visual Studio](http://www.coderetard.com/2009/01/21/generate-a-lib-from-a-dll-with-visual-studio/)
[How To Create 32-bit Import Libraries Without .OBJs or Source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131313)

Answer (score 0):

the free and working tool you mention is call "linker". one you could use is part of the package called "visual studio" from microsoft, the free version is called "[visual studio express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2008-Visual-CPP)"

anyway, your real problem is that you need the .lib file used to resolve the link-time dependencies. you can grab the code for the mysql-connector and compile it yourself .. or you just grab the binaries provided by mysql [over there](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/).

i would pick up the .zip file provided for your architecture, unzip it and look into the "lib" folder. furthermore i would place the whole unzipped bundle to a place on your disk (i prefer "C:\Devel" .. so it becomes "C:\Devel\mysql-6.0.2-win32") and then add the "include" directory to the preprocessor settings and the "lib" directory to the linker settings.